# Is there a table with decomposition temperatures of common minerals?

Tags: mineralogy, minerals

I am about to perform a Loss On Ignition test on a material I know that contains among on things kaolinite, which will release water at 500 $^oC$. However, I tried finding a table with decomposition temperatures of common minerals that lose their water, or carbon, or whatever, at a certain temperature or temperature interval.

Anyone familiar with a freely accessible table?

Comment: Minerals are not exact chemical compounds so you will not find one, they are a combination of chemical composition and crystal strucutre.  Many minerals become other minerals before they "decompose". The second problem is the chemical stability of most minerals is pressure dependent, so you are not looking a a point but a curve or diagram for each mineral. The closest you will find is phase stability diagrams.  Lastly there are about 5000 named minerals, most with multiple variants and some are poorly studied. You are trying to find a table of something that just does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected to find something [here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/) but there isn't a guide to ceramics there that I can find. This [article](http://ousar.lib.okayama-u.ac.jp/files/public/1/15437/20160527210146171135/Mem_Fac_Eng_OU_28_1_51.pdf) and it's references may give you some guidance though. Found a limited table in [this](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783540312109-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-174599-p115687972) that will probably help too.